# ImportError: cannot import name parser with tika-python

Tags: python, apache-tika

Done with :

- java -jar tika-server-path --port xxxx
- pip install tika (virtualenv)

parser-tika.py

```
  import tika 
  from tika import parser 
  parsed = parser.from_file('/path/to/file')
  print parsed["metadata"]
  print parsed["content"]
```

error :
      ImportError: cannot import name parser

env setup:

```
TIKA_VERSION=1.13.1
TIKA_SERVER_JAR=~/parserDev/tika/tika-server-1.13.jar
TIKA_SERVER_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8989/tika
```

Comment: maybe you created file `tika.py` and now it imports your file instead of expected module.

Comment: Such a lame mistake thank you. @furas

Comment: @Aswin can you give me a tip, where I need to put the TIKA_SERVER_JAR directive?

Comment: @erfelipe You can put it anywhere and start server from the same location. It worked for me.

Comment: @furas you are a saver dude

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a file called `tika.py` in the current directory because that's the name of a different `tika` you are trying to import.

Simply rename your file.